# notify_observers not working in production environment

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I updated rails from '3.0.20' to '3.2.13'. For rails '3.0.20' observer is working fine for all environments. But rails '3.2.13' it works in development environment but fails in production environment. If I call the observer instance from console it works fine.

I have added all observers to application.rb file.

```
 config.active_record.observers = :abc_observer, :top_observer
```

I have called notify method from ABC class like

```
def update_data
  notify_observers :update_data_for_abc
end
```

I have tried hard but could not able to resolve the problem.
Can any one please help me resolving the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the observers to the specific environment, works fine for me.
On your case add:

```
config.active_record.observers = :notification_observer
```

to app/config/production.rb